# Penalizing flow file causes following processor to accumulate Task/Time

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to delay flow files. Do to so I use a ExecuteScript processor with following code:

```
flowFile = session.get() 
if(!flowFile) return 
session.penalize(flowFile) 
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

It simply penalizes the flow file for a certain amount of time. However as you see in the image, the following UpdateAttribute processor accumulates Task/Time.

[image]

Why does this happen? Does the flow file get fed into the UpdateAttribute processor, which recognizes that the flow file is penalized, thus causing the processor to do some work? Is it something to worry about?

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue about this behavior:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3229

and it is still open...